# fastest way to move large record table mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Please help me found out this solution.im handling a very large record of data like 2M of student test result record.All record was stored in one table,what i need to do is separate this record into two different table,one for all pass student the other is for fail student.after separate this record i need to delete the origin record from the source table.each time im running this code it take more than hours to finish.If anyone out there can help me find out the solution it would be great.thanks.

here is the sample code:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php
function spread($classselect,$subjectselect)
{include "connectdb.php";

//movepass

$selectpass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testresultAUG2012 WHERE actualmonth='AUG' AND testresult = 'PASS' AND classname = '$classselect' AND educationsubject = $subjectselect;",$conn);
$totalpass = mysql_num_rows($selectpass);
$pass=0;
while($pass<$totalpass)
{
    $name=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "Studentname");
    $subject=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "Subject");
    $testbatch=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "testbatch");
    $classname=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "class");
    $lecturer=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "lecturer");
    $date=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "date");
    $month=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "month");
    $time=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "time");
    $state=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "result");

    //count total pass subject and add 1
    $totalpass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Studentname = '$name';",$conn);
    $only = mysql_fetch_array($theone);
    $currentpass = $only['totalpass'];
    $newpass = $currentpass + 1;
    mysql_query("UPDATE Student SET totalpass = $newpass WHERE Studentname = '$name';",$conn);

    //save record to pass table
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO passtab(......) VALUES(....);",$conn);

    //remove data from origin table
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM testresultAUG2012 WHERE Studentname = '$name' AND testbatch = $testbatch AND Subject=$subject AND result = 'PASS' AND class = '$classname';",$conn);
    $pass++;
}

//moveFailed

$selectfail = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM testresultAUG2012 WHERE actualmonth='AUG' AND testresult = 'PASS' AND classname = '$classselect' AND educationsubject = $subjectselect;",$conn);
$totalfail = mysql_num_rows($selectfail);
$fail=0;
while($fail<$totalfail)
{
    $name=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "Studentname");
    $subject=mysql_result($selectpass, $fail, "Subject");
    $testbatch=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "testbatch");
    $classname=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "class");
    $lecturer=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "lecturer");
    $date=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "date");
    $month=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "month");
    $time=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "time");
    $state=mysql_result($selectfail, $fail, "result");

    //count total fail subject and add 1
    mysql_query("UPDATE Student SET totalfail = totalfail + 1  WHERE Studentname = '$name';",$conn);

    //save record to fail table
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO failtab(....) VALUES(...);",$conn);


    //remove data from origin table
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM testresultAUG2012 WHERE Studentname = '$name' AND testbatch = $testbatch AND Subject=$subject AND result = 'FAIL' AND class = '$classname';",$conn);
    $fail++;
    }
}
?>
<?php
$relatedclass=$_POST[classup];
$relatedsubject=$_POST[subject];
spread($relatedclass,$relatedsubject);
echo "<center>Spread Completed !!!</CENTER>";

?>
<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: Why not just add a boolean column to show if the student passed or failed?

Comment: Avoid using **select** *,use fields instead

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't fetch all the data from the database then send it back again row by row.

If you had a bag of sand on your lawn and you wanted to give it your neighbour, what would you do? Would you leave him a note telling him that he can take it? Or would you first send the entire bag to your uncle in Russia then tell your uncle to post it back to your neighbour one grain at a time? The way you are handling your data is more like the latter approach.

Do something like this instead:

```
INSERT INTO table1
(col1, col2, ... coln)
SELECT col1, col2, ... coln
FROM table2
WHERE result = 'PASS'
```

Comment: Dear Mark,when im using this querry  INSERT INTO table1
(col1, col2, ... coln)
SELECT col1, col2, ... coln
FROM table2
WHERE result = 'PASS' how can i  add the pass rate to student and delete the record while im not running any loop?thanks

Comment: let say i wan to make some thing like this, insert into table 1(col1,col2,col3,col4) select colA,colB.colC,colD,colE from table 2 where result ='PASS'.the col 2 is actually the combination of col b and c.thanks

Comment: @tora: You will have to run two commands. One INSERT and one DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the queries from while loop and run the query outside the loop but generate the query string inside the loop.i mean instead of running query every time you can insert all the data by using one query ,you can try following solution

```
while($pass<$totalpass)
{
    $name=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "Studentname");
    $subject=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "Subject");
    $testbatch=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "testbatch");
    $classname=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "class");
    $lecturer=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "lecturer");
    $date=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "date");
    $month=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "month");
    $time=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "time");
    $state=mysql_result($selectpass, $pass, "result");

    //count total pass subject and add 1
    $totalpass = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE Studentname = '$name';",$conn);
    $only = mysql_fetch_array($theone);
    $currentpass = $only['totalpass'];
    $newpass = $currentpass + 1;


    //save record to pass table
   $values[]='('.$valuestring.')'(//whatever you want to ineser)

    //remove data from origin table

    $pass++;
}
```

mysql_query(insert into tyablename ('') values (implode(',',$values)))

Comment: Thanks alot Sumit,it was a helpful resource